# Border radius does not work with I.E.?

Tags: css

Css

```
border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
background-color: #000;
background: rgb(51,51,51); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(51,51,51,1) 0%, rgba(153,153,153,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(51,51,51,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(153,153,153,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(51,51,51,1) 0%,rgba(153,153,153,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(51,51,51,1) 0%,rgba(153,153,153,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(51,51,51,1) 0%,rgba(153,153,153,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(51,51,51,1) 0%,rgba(153,153,153,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#333333', endColorstr='#999999',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
```

Chrome and FireFox Output:

[image]

I.E. Output:

[image]

What is the problem about this? I cant find any think. How can I fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of IE is this? Also, the CSS you provided isn't a border-related style.

Comment: Depends on IE version and document mode. Btw: `box-shadow` != `border-radius` :)

Comment: Your CSS is for box-shadow not border-radius

Comment: So you showed us the CSS for `box-shadow` and the problem is the `border-radius`? :) Although, it is helpful; judging by the fact that the `box-shadow` does happen on IE, you've probably specified the prefixed versions of `border-radius` (e.g. `-webkit-border-radius` and `-moz-border-radius`), but not `border-radius`.

Comment: Your CSS is for the `box-shadow`, not `border-radius`

Comment: After 5 people telling you, I hope that you now realise box-shadow is different from border-radius.

Comment: IE version is 9. I dont use box-shadow. But I use css gradient. Is this problem?

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi: If you're not using `box-shadow`... where did that CSS come from? Can you please show the relevant code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `filter` is the problem:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#333333', endColorstr='#999999',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Using a `filter` to provide a background gradient will make `border-radius` ineffective. So it's either the round corners or the fancy background on IE9. I'm sorry. :)

... just kidding. You can use another box shadow!

```
box-shadow: inset 0 -1em 1em -0.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
```

Adjust that until you get something that looks like the gradient.

Comment: +1 Everytime I read your answers I learn something new... God dam

Comment: yes you right. But what can I use instead of filter? I think I should use images instead of gradients?

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi: `box-shadow`! [Here's a demo.](http://dabblet.com/gist/4032249)

Answer (score 1):

`border-radius` is only supported on IE9+

Refer to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) for future browser compatibility info:

http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius

Comment: Although the `box-shadow` seems to work pretty well ;) http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow

Answer (score 1):

```
.round {
  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android 1.6- */
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px; 

  /* Firefox 1-3.6 */
  -moz-border-radius:    12px; 

  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Safari 5, Chrome, Firefox 4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
  border-radius: 12px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Border Radius is not supported on IE 7 & 8.
You can still have both border-radius and linear-gradients in IE 7 & 8 by using [PIE.HTC - Progressive Internet Explorer HTML Component](http://css3pie.com/). It also supports gradients. So not use filter.